# Using values from text file to App.config

Tags: c#

I have a text file in C:\temp\DateFile.txt which has a date in the first line and nothing else.
  I have a C# Program that has a SQL statement in App.config file

```
<add key="selectstmt" value="select HomeID from dbo.AllHomes where InsertedDate >
  ''
  ">
```

I want to use the date from DateFile.txt in the sql statement. 
**InsertedDate > Date from DateFile.txt**

How can I do it.

Thanks
Rs

Comment: You can read the "selectstmt" from the config, then read the "DateFile.txt" from the disk, then concatenate the two strings before executing.

Comment: But how can I do it? I use `string line = File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\DataFile.txt")  sqlCommandReader.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["selectstmt"].ToString();`  to read it.

Comment: `sqlCommandReader.CommandText =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["selectstmt"].ToString() + File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\DataFile.txt")`. However you will probably want to use bind variables.